# Why is there a difference in the content when inspecting a webpage using chrome and scraping it using BeatifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the following webpage:

```
https://www.comparis.ch/immobilien/marktplatz/details/show/16792498
```

When I use inspector in Chrome, I can see the coordinates in the following html snippet:

```
<div data-fi-hf-streetview="" data-fi-hf-streetview-objectid="map-panorama-
streetview" data-fi-hf-streetview-latitude="47.373122178099064444511111111"
data-fi-hf-streetview-longitude="8.539781976138127069261111111" data-fi-hf
streetview-language="De" style="display:none;"></div>
```

However, when I use BeautifulSoup to scrape the webpage, I cannot see this content anymore? Why is that? I use the following code to scrape it:

```
url = "https://www.comparis.ch/immobilien/marktplatz/details/show/16792498"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
```

Even before extracting it, I cannot see the coordinates anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the HTML that your browser shows you is actually generated by Javascript at runtime.

Comment: @ BoarGules Thank you for your answer. Bottom line, I cannot scrape it?

Comment: You could try using `selenium`.

Comment: I actually tried that because I thought I need to click on the "map button". However, it didn't work either...

Comment: Now it works, I had to use the WebDriverWait to wait until the content is created. Thanks a lot for the hint!